# Use webuploader always remind 'abort'

Tags: javascript, web, upload

In my project, we need to upload files to server,so i used 'webuploader' module,but the page always remind me -- 'abort', unable to submit the request to the server,i don't know why,please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why,but when i changed the module's version,it became great.